# How to display received data from php properly in jquery dialog table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

There is a jquery dialog with a table where I would like to add some rows upon the information received from php script (potrawyINFOEngine.php). It looks that scripts sends the data correctly but I cannot upload it into the table, I get 'undefined' messages loaded into the table instead.
Messages from a browsers console looks OK to me showing that the data has been send back from php script.
Can you please help me with this?
​
Please look at the code attached:

```
$("#dialog-message1").hide();
$('.confirmation1').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var lnk = $(this).attr('href');
    var product_name = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").first().html();
    console.log(product_name);

    $("#dialog-message1").append("<table id='tableINFO'> </table>");
    $("#dialog-message1 table").append("<tr><th>Nazwa produktu</th><th>Waga (g)</th><th>Kalorie (Kcal)</th> <th>Białko (g)</th> <th>Tłuszcze (g)</th> i<th>Węglowodany (g)</th> </tr>");

    console.log(product_name);

         $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "potrawyINFOEngine.php",
            data: {"nazwa": product_name},
         }).done(function( data ) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            var len = data.length;
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                    var T_nazwaproduktu = data[i].produkt;
                    var T_waga = data[i].waga;
                    var T_kalorie = data[i].kalorie;
                    var T_bialko = data[i].bialko;
                    var T_tluszcze = data[i].tluszcze;
                    var T_weglowodany = data[i].weglowodany;

                    var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                            "<td align='left'>" + T_nazwaproduktu + "</td>" +
                            "<td align='left'>" + T_waga + "</td>" +
                            "<td align='left'>" + T_kalorie + "</td>" +
                            "<td align='left'>" + T_bialko + "</td>" +
                            "<td align='left'>" + T_tluszcze + "</td>" +
                            "<td align='left'>" + T_weglowodany + "</td>" +
                            "</tr>";

                    $("#dialog-message1 table").append(tr_str);

            }
            console.log(result);


      });


    $("#dialog-message1").dialog({
        height: "auto",
        width: 700,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $( "#dialog-message1 table" ).remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

UPDATE:
Please see the php script:

```
<?php

include 'db_connection.php';
include 'functions.php';


$return_arr = array();

error_log("-->potrawaINFOEngine.php:"."\n", 3, "/var/www/html/jadlospis/errors.log");

if (isset($_POST['nazwa'])){

        $T_NazwaPotrawy = $_POST['nazwa'];

        $SQL = "SELECT produkt AS T_P, waga AS T_W FROM potrawydetails WHERE nazwa='".$T_NazwaPotrawy."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$SQL ) or die(mysqli_error($this->dblink));
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
                $T_Produkt=$row['T_P'];
                $T_Waga=$row['T_W'];

                $T_ProduktDetails=ProduktyDetails($T_Produkt,$T_Waga);

                $T_Kalorie=$T_ProduktDetails['kalorie'];
                $T_Bialko=$T_ProduktDetails['bialko'];
                $T_Tluszcze=$T_ProduktDetails['tluszcze'];
                $T_Weglowodany=$T_ProduktDetails['weglowodany'];

                error_log("-->".$T_Produkt.",".$T_Waga.",".$T_Kalorie."\n", 3, "/var/www/html/jadlospis/errors.log");

                $return_arr[] = array(  "produkt" => $T_Produkt,
                                        "waga" => $T_Waga,
                                        "kalorie" => $T_Kalorie,
                                        "bialko" => $T_Bialko,
                                        "tluszcze" => $T_Tluszcze,
                                        "weglowodany" => $T_Weglowodany);

        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
        echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
?>
```

Please see attached screen:

[image: Console log]

Comment: Are you sending back JSON? Would be good to see the code thats running on the server, or the data that is being returned

Comment: Run the browser debugger, set a breakpont on the line `var result = $.parseJSON(data);` and trace it line by line till you see your mistake

Comment: It would also be good to see what `data` actually contains. Do a `console.log(data);` instead of the `result` (which you don't even seem to be using).

Comment: I just added the php script

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized prepared statements instead of concatenating your query with unescaped user data.

Comment: **Warning!** It is not necessary to move each array occurance into a scalar. Why not just use the array occurance instead

Comment: You send back JSON.... You parse that JSON from `data` into `result` **and then you use `data` for all the remaining code ??????**

Comment: I have to ask... what browser and OS are you using and what versions?

Comment: I am aware of security lacks, but I will take care of it when application is done. I use centos on the server and win7 on client with latest firefox and chrome

Comment: _"but I will take care of it when application is done"_ - The famous last words before you get breached. It's way easier to miss updating some piece of code than if you do it correctly from the start. Also, why would you spend time building and debugging code that you just need to rebuild and debug yet again when it's done? There's simply never a good reason for knowingly writing insecure code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the hints. The solution that worked for me was using result instead of data.

Please see attached code:

```
     $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "potrawyINFOEngine.php",
        data: {"nazwa": product_name},
     }).done(function( data ) {
        var result = $.parseJSON(data);
        var len = result.length;
        for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var T_nazwaproduktu = result[i].produkt;
                var T_waga = result[i].waga;
                var T_kalorie = result[i].kalorie;
                var T_bialko = result[i].bialko;
                var T_tluszcze = result[i].tluszcze;
                var T_weglowodany = result[i].weglowodany;

                var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                        "<td align='left'>" + T_nazwaproduktu + "</td>" +
                        "<td align='left'>" + T_waga + "</td>" +
                        "<td align='left'>" + T_kalorie + "</td>" +
                        "<td align='left'>" + T_bialko + "</td>" +
                        "<td align='left'>" + T_tluszcze + "</td>" +
                        "<td align='left'>" + T_weglowodany + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>";

                $("#dialog-message1 table").append(tr_str);

        }
        console.log(data);
  });
```

Now the table looks much better. 
[image: screen1]

Thanks to all.